# Apply square wave function to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I can quickly apply a cos function as follows to a float32 numpy array:

```
 cos_f = np.vectorize(lambda x: math.cos(2 * math.pi * x))
 signal = square_f(integral)
```

However if I try this:

```
 square_f = np.vectorize(lambda x: sig.square(2 * math.pi * x))
 signal = square_f(integral)
```

it takes 15 seconds for 60,000 samples. `integral` has a length of 1024 and is used as a buffer.

How should I be applying the square wave to my signal?

Comment: Where does `sig.square()` come from? Is it code you wrote, or imported from another library?

Comment: please provide all the variables you use in your code

Comment: `signal` is the same in both tries. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sig.square(2*np.pi * x)` is three times slower than `np.cos(2*np.pi * x)`, however, this is not a bottleneck here. This nice `np.vectorize` - based decoration actually costs 120x slowdown! The reason why this happens is that `square_f` applies `scipy.signal.square` on items being iterated which is a bunch of aritmetics designed to work with arrays instead (unlike `math.cos`). This is an example of arithmetics done inside `scipy.signal.square`:

```
def example(x, w=0.5):
    return (1 - (w > 1) | (w < 0)) & (np.mod(x, 2 * pi) < w * 2 * np.pi)
```

Assuming `arr` is a large array, this is obviously more efficient to call `example(arr)` instead of

```
ex = np.vectorize(lambda x: example(x))
ex(arr)
```

The timings show that as well:

```
arr = np.linspace(0,1,1000000)
%timeit ex(arr)
%timeit example(arr)
8.13 s ± 208 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
18.5 ms ± 1.14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure you need the `np.vectorize` here at all:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal as sig

integral = np.linspace(0, 10, 1024)
signal1 = np.cos(2*np.pi * integral)
signal2 = sig.square(2*np.pi * integral)
```

You can of course also create a function and than call it with
an array as input:

```py
def cos2pi(x):
    return np.cos(2*np.pi * x)

signal1 = cos2pi(integral)
```

And one could go even further and call the function just once for all samples simultaneously.

```
samples = np.random.random((60000, 1024))
signal1 = cos2pi(samples)
```

Comment: Is there any cases where `np.vectorize` is worth using at all?