# How to parallelize writing to same cell in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, parallel-processing, 2d

**Background**: I have millions of points in 2D space with `(x_position, y_position, value)` associated with each point. I am trying to summarize these points by creating an image, where each pixel can contain multiple points. To summarize, each pixel stores the sum of `value`s at that `(x_pixel, y_pixel)` location in the image.

**Question**: How can I do this efficiently? Currently, my code does something like this:

```
image = np.zeros((4096,4096))
for each point in data:
    x_pixel, y_pixel = convertPointPos2PixelPos(point)
    image[x_pixel, y_pixel] += point.getValue()
```

but the ETA for this code completing is 450 hours, which is unacceptable. Is there a way to parallelize this? The code is writing to the same `image[x,y]` index multiple times. I found StackOverflow posts that suggest using `multiprocessing`, but I think needing to `lock` to prevent race conditions will mean this will take just as much time as it would without parallelizing.

Comment: It depends a lot on whether `convertPointPos2PixelPos` can be vectorized. In worst scenario you are iterating with method that is designed to work with arrays instead like [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64083345/3044825)

Comment: What is point? what is data? Please post an MCVE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want something on a regular grid, you can use simple division to bin your data. Here is an example:

```
size = (4096, 4096)
data = np.random.rand(100000000, 3)
image = np.zeros(size)

coords = data[:, :2]
min = coords.min(0)
max = coords.max(0)

index = np.floor_divide(coords - min, (max - min) / np.subtract(size, 1), out=np.empty(coords.shape, dtype=int), casting='unsafe')
```

`index` is now an array of indices into `image` where you want to add the corresponding values. You can do an unbuffered add using [`np.add.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
np.add.at(image, tuple(index.T), data[:, -1])
```

If your data range is better defined than just the bounding box of the coordinates, you can save a little time by not computing `coord.max()` and `coord.min()`.

The result is something like this:

[image]

This entire operation takes 6.4sec on my very moderately powered machine for 10M points, including the call to `plt.imshow`, `plt.colorbar` and garbage collection before runs.

Timing collected using the `%%timeit` cell magic in IPython.

Either way, you're well under 450 hours. Even if your coordinate transformation is not linear binning, I expect that you can run in reasonable time as long as you vectorize it properly. Also, multiprocessing is not likely to give you a huge boost since it requires copying data around.